# How to make a datatable column clickable

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I am making a table

HTML tag

```
<table id="example" class="display" onload="callData()"></table>
```

javascript

```
function dataIsSet(){
var dataSet=[];
syncAjaxCall("POST","getGridData" ,"", "application/json")
.done(
        function(data) {
            if(data.response.Status==1){
            for(i=0;i<data.response.Result.length; i++){

                dataSet.push([])
            }
            for(i=0;i<data.response.Result.length; i++){
                dataSet[i].push(data.response.Result[i].interestsName);
                dataSet[i].push(data.response.Result[i].subscriberCount);
                dataSet[i].push(data.response.Result[i].messageCount);
            }
            }
            else
                showMessage("green", data.response.Description, "");
        });
if (dataSet[0].length==3)
    return dataSet;
}
function callData() {
debugger;
$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataIsSet(),
    columns: [
              { title: "Interest Name" },
              { title: "No of Subscribers" },
              { title: "No of Messages" }
              ] ,

 } );

 }
```

My javascript file

```
  <script src="interests/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">               </script>
   <script src="interests/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My css file

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interests/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
```

Now I want to make no. of messages column a link where it will take value from interest name.

Comment: simply add `<a>` with a path in href where you want to link it

Answer (score 0):

Just insert them inside of PutItHeretag buddy.

Comment: hi actually the data added is dynamically and I am not able to make it a link